# ¿Cómo definir métodos correctamente en TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Dado el siguiente código en TypeScript

```
class Persona {
    constructor(public nombre: string, public apellido: string) {
    }

    nombreCompleto1 = () => {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }

    nombreCompleto2() {
        return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
    }
}

var p = new Persona("Juan", "Pérez");

console.log(p.nombreCompleto1());
console.log(p.nombreCompleto2());
```

Como se puede ver los métodos `nombreCompleto1` y `nombreCompleto2` hacen lo mismo pero están declarados ligeramente diferente.

Al ejecutarlo en los dos casos se obtiene el resultado esperado:

```
Juan Pérez
Juan Pérez
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos declaraciones si los dos hacen los mismo y cuál es la forma adecuada de declararlo?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

En el primer caso:

```
nombreCompleto1 = () => {
    return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
}
```

estás creando un *método de instancia*, es equivalente a ejecutar `this.nombreCompleto1 = function() {...}` en JavaScript.

En el segundo caso:

```
nombreCompleto2() {
    return this.nombre + " " + this.apellido;
}
```

estás creando un *método de prototipo*, es equivalente a `Persona.prototype.nombreCompleto2 = function() {...}` en JavaScript.

En general es preferible crear métodos de prototipo: en tal caso el método se define una sola vez, mientras que los métodos de instancia se crean una vez por instancia, consumiendo más memoria.

Más información: [TypeScript Classes and Interfaces](http://www.johnpapa.net/typescriptpost3)

Comment: Y cuál de los dos es el recomendable y porque?... (para completar la respuesta)

Comment: Cierto. ¡Añadido!